# Converting a string to XML datatype before querying in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

How do I convert a string into an XML datatype so that I can query the data as XML:

For example (thanks to "mellamokb the Wise" who provided the original SQL for this)

The code below works fine if xmlstring is of the type XML (see [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e452/6))

```
select id, name
from Data
cross apply (
  select Destination.value('data(@Name)', 'varchar(50)') as name
  from [xmlstring].nodes('/Holidays/Summer/Regions/Destinations/Destination') D(Destination)
) Destinations(Name)
```

However, if xmlString is of type varchar I get an error even though I'm converting the string to XML ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c51e60/5)):

```
select id, name
from Data
  cross apply (
  select Destination.value('data(@Name)', 'varchar(50)') as name
  from CONVERT(xml,[xmlstring]).nodes('/Holidays/Summer/Regions/Destinations/Destination') D(Destination)
) Destinations(Name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the cast it in one extra cross apply.

```
select id,
       T.N.value('@Name', 'varchar(50)') as name
from Data
cross apply (select cast(xmlstring as xml)) as X(X)
cross apply X.X.nodes('/Holidays/Summer/Regions/Destinations/Destination') T(N)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c51e60/6)

There might be performance issues with casting to XML. Have a look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34716/2103) and [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30862/optimising-plans-with-xml-readers/30947#30947)