# select value of specific attribute of xml document with multiple elements stored in SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have got the following XML document shown below stored in the NVARCHAR column `xmlfile` of my table `exampletable`. The order of the property-elements differs as well as the amount of elements.

```
<properties>
    <property name="LEAD" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
    <property name="CONTACT" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
    <property name="PROSPECT" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
</properties>
```

I'm able to select what I need as long as I specify the correct element with:

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable
WHERE CONVERT(xml,xmlfile).value('(/properties/property/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'PROSPECT'
```

But how can I dynamically look for the needed attribute no matter on which position the element is?

Here is the SQL to create the example:

```
CREATE TABLE #exampletable
(     
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    xmlfile NVARCHAR(max)
);
INSERT INTO #exampletable (xmlfile) 
VALUES ('<properties><property name="LEAD" newValue="0" oldValue="" /><property name="CONTACT" newValue="0" oldValue="" /><property name="PROSPECT" newValue="0" oldValue="" /></properties>')
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and can be done without any CROSS APPLY statements.

Below is sample data with another record where the "@name = LEAD" element is not first.

```
-- Sample data with another record
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('#exampletable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #exampletable;
GO
CREATE TABLE #exampletable
(     
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    xmlfile NVARCHAR(max)
);
INSERT INTO #exampletable (xmlfile)
VALUES 
('<properties>
<property name="LEAD" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
<property name="CONTACT" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
<property name="PROSPECT" newValue="0" oldValue="" />
</properties>'),
('<properties>
<property name="CONTACT" newValue="10" oldValue="5" />
<property name="LEAD" newValue="2" oldValue="1" />
<property name="PROSPECT" newValue="6" oldValue="" />
</properties>');
GO

-- Solution
SELECT 
  ID,
  oldValue = CAST(XMLfile AS xml).value('(/properties/property[@name="LEAD"]/@oldValue)[1]','varchar(10)'),
  newValue = CAST(XMLfile AS xml).value('(/properties/property[@name="LEAD"]/@newValue)[1]','varchar(10)')
FROM #exampletable;
```

Results:

```
ID          oldValue   newValue
----------- ---------- ----------
1                      0
2           1          2
```

Comment: thank you for response. it is a bit fast than mine!  Following where condition works for me, to only show the entries with the attribute name with value LEAD: `WHERE 
 CAST(xmlfile as xml).exist('/properties/property[@name="LEAD"]') = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself with help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136634/2893242

```
SELECT
    T.N.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') as name,
    T.N.value('@oldValue', 'varchar(50)') as oldValue,
    T.N.value('@newValue', 'varchar(50)') as newValue
FROM exampletable xt
cross apply (select cast(xmlfile as xml)) as S(F) 
cross apply S.F.nodes('/properties/property') T(N)
WHERE T.N.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') = 'LEAD' AND SA.id = @id
```